# How to find Mongolian tutors in Sydney

Tags: tutoring

How do I find Mongolian tutors in Sydney, Australia?

I'm trying to find a tutor for Mongolian in Sydney, but haven't had much luck.

I managed to find one tutor who is a native speaker, but she'll soon be unavailable to give me lessons. Her ads on locanto.com.au and www.world-tutor-hub.com have been taken down.

[This person](http://www.tutorfinder.com.au/tutors/detail.php?TutorID=61178) teaches Mongolian, but is not a native speaker.

I tried googling for "Mongolian lessons Sydney" (minus quotes) and "Mongolian tutor Sydney" (minus quotes) and didn't get anything, apart from the two tutors mentioned above.

Doing a search of Mongolian in the Sydney region on [Gumtree](http://www.gumtree.com.au/s-sydney/mongolian/k0l3003435?fromSearchBox=true) didn't get any relevant hits.

Searching Italki for a Mongolian teacher only got one person, who is in Ulaan Baatar.

Comment: Oh, this seems to be a *too narrow* question!

Comment: I've asked a [meta question](http://meta.languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/277/are-specific-questions-how-to-find-a-tutor-in-x-teaching-language-y-on-topic) concerning this subject to see if the community thinks these types of questions are on-topic.

Comment: Also, is it necessary that the tutor lives in your area? Is there a reason you can't do Skype calls every week and have your lesson like that?

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind having [Skype](https://www.skype.com/en/) lessons with your tutor, I found a [Mongolian tutor](http://www.glovico.org/teacher/1304) named Zoljargal Baatarkhuu, who currently lives in France. He's a native speaker who charges USD$13.50 a lesson. (I'm not actually sure how long each lesson is, so you may need to get in contact with him to learn that.)

34 of his past students have reviewed him, commenting on his astounding clarity, patience, and professionalism, and he averages a 5 star rating, so he does seem to be a pretty experienced teacher.

*Note: In no way am I affiliated with Glovico (the service that offers the tutor), so I'm not commenting on the quality of this service, as I've never tried it. I'm also not sponsored by them. I do not take responsibility for any of your actions in relation to this organization.*

Answer (score 0):

I've been having similar problems(although not in Sydney). I think finding a face-to-face tutor would be impossible, especially with Covid restrictions. I did consider a lady on preply But her prices are a little high for me at the moment...I was disappointed that Duolingo didn't have Mongolian in its language options, and apparently, they don't see a market for lesser-known languages. I've been using Ling for the last few weeks and am progressing nicely, although I do think I need to combine it with occasional speaking classes. Wishing you luck.